# Connect to MongoDb using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to connect a Spring Boot REST Api project to a MongoDb via *aplication.properties* file. Why? Because it seems easier to me.

I know how to do this connection with a MySQL db. I have downloaded MongoDb Compass GUI.

**application.properties file**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/springtest
spring.data.mongodb.username=mihai
spring.data.mongodb.password=mihai
```

I use *uri* because I have found that if the MongoDb version is > 3.x.x you should use that. My MongoDb version is 4.4.4

Users collection: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raWVh.jpg)

pom file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--##################################################-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UserRepository file:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<Users, String> {

}
```

Main application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AdServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I get the following error trance:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

From my research I found that the problem might be because of the configuration provided in the application.properties file but I don't really know how to write it properly for MongoDb.

For instance if I change the application.properties content to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=mihai
spring.datasource.password=mihai
```

It works perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And use the configuration

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/springtest
spring.data.mongodb.username=mihai
spring.data.mongodb.password=mihai
```

When you add the dependency it requires a datasource url that you not provide

Comment: I did that. Now I have the following error: `Consider defining a bean of type com.servizone.app.dao.UserRepository`. I have all my packages below the main package app. I am struggling to debug it but I can't find a way because all the solutions are about using _ComponentScan_ which is not needed if you have the right package hierarchy and also using the @Repository annotation which I have already tried.

Comment: I started the project again with the same files and the server started buy I get the whitelabel error page while accessing _http://localhost:8080/_:
`This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Apr 01 03:48:31 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`

Comment: if you have no mapping it's normal. Show your controller and ask another question, your problem is resolved

Comment: I don't have a controller. To my understanding if I extend the _MongoRepository_ I will get for free the crud methods and the *endpoints* of the class _Users_. Correct me if I am wrong. Like in a JPA Repository [link](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-restful-jpa-repositories/)

Comment: I made it work by adding the dependency:
`<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
 `
And here are all the other project dependencies:
`<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 `

Answer (score 0):

remove the spring-data-jpa
`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency>` 
because you're using a no-relational database (MongoDB) jpa is used only for relational database
and it will work.